# Display prestahop customizable text only when a combination is selected

Tags: prestashop

I have a shop with 2 combinations. Yes and No. I added a customizable text to my products but I would like this text area to appear only when "yes" is selected. Can someone please help me do this?

Thanks!

Edit:

Thank you for replying. My code looks like this now:

```
//init the serialScroll for thumbs
$('#thumbs_list').serialScroll({
    items:'li:visible',
    prev:'#view_scroll_left',
    next:'#view_scroll_right',
    axis:'x',
    offset:0,
    start:0,
    stop:true,
    onBefore:serialScrollFixLock,
    duration:700,
    step: 2,
    lazy: true,
    lock: false,
    force:false,
    cycle:false
});

$('#group_22').change(function() {
$('.idTab10').toggle();
```

});

Sadly it doesn't work. Nothing happens. The (Yes) select ID is 22. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you do that with jQuery.

You just have to modify the file /themes/your_theme/js/product.js
In this file, search for:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    ...
});
```

At the end of it, add the following code:

```
toggleCustomization(); // We launch the function on page load
$('#group_4').change(function() { // We launch the function when select is changed
    toggleCustomization();
});
```

And right after closing $(document).ready(function(), add this function :

```
function toggleCustomization() { // Hide or Show Customization Form and Tab
    if($('#group_4').val() == '23') { // We hide Customization Form and Tab if No is selected
        $('#idTab10').hide();
        $('a[href="#idTab10"]').hide();
    } else { // We show Customization Form and Tab if Yes is selected
        $('#idTab10').show();
        $('a[href="#idTab10"]').show();
    }
};
```

Where:

- group_4 is the id of your Yes-No select
- idTab10 is the id of the bloc containing all information about your customization field
- 23 is the value of 'No' in your select

Comment: blobmarket, thank you for replying. I tried what you advised but sadly it does not work. Nothing happens. I updated my question and I included the code. I tried many variants of classes and still nothing. Please advise. Thank you!

Comment: Isn't idTab10 an ID ? In this case your code should be `$('#idTab10').toggle();`

Comment: What I did is: clicked on view source and searched for the line that handles this customization field. I don't think idTab10 is an ID. The line looks like this: <div id="idTab10" class="bullet customization_block">. What I know for sure is that 22 is the ID for the Yes select. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Ok, so you must either use `$('.customization_block').toggle();` or `$('#idTab10').toggle();` . Notice the # before idTab10

Comment: Thank you again for your time. I tried modifying the lines as you mentioned but still no go. I even cleared the smarty cache, just in case. Any more suggestions please? Will it help if I share the website's address?

Comment: Yes please, share your website's address. I'll take a look.

Comment: Based on this page, your Yes-No select id is group_4. So the working code is:
`$('#group_4').change(function() {
    $('#idTab10').toggle();
});`

Comment: I just edited the code in my answer to fit your shop code. I also added a line to hide the Customization Tab.

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for your help. Sadly it's not working. I opened Firefox's Web Console, and I see here the following: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list product.js:511
SyntaxError: syntax error search.js:1
ReferenceError: addCombination is not defined 8-invitatie-de-nunta-cod-1000-odiseea.html:525
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. jquery-1.7.2.min.js:3
ReferenceError: findCombination is not defined. Please advise.

Comment: In your product.js you have put `function toggleCustomization() {...};` between `$(document).ready(function()` and `{`. Put it before `$(document).ready(function()` or after `$(document).ready(function(){...});`